# Scala in image processing

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, image-processing

I am new to scala and keep on researching and compiling programs , But i am more interested in Image processing in scala. Iam doing project in eclipse environment from http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.0-M5.html but i couldn't find any resource to do image processing in scala . please provide me all information

i.e How to install image processing package till manuals of the package to read and write image.

I have tried Maven ,jmagic,opencv ,javacv etc but couldn't succeeded. Please reply with in hours my job is at stake.

Mayank

Comment: Please make your problem more specific. Example if you failed installing a package, what is the error message, what steps have you tried, etc.

Comment: I have to Build a project in scala for image processing , I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard Java image processing libraries from Scala. It depends on *how* you want to process your images.

- [Java Image IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/)
- [Processing](http://processing.org/)
- [Java Image Filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/)
- [Scala Pure Image library](https://github.com/stephenjudkins/pureimage)

> Please reply with in hours my job is at stake

If you are telling us that you need to learn Scala, Java, image processing, Maven management, and Eclipse in hours, you should perhaps rethink your time management.

Comment: Sorry for you miss understanding, this is because i have to submit project for a company till Wednesday and i am good in java and scala, maven is just an option. i have to submit in scala. i am using eclipse  environment. So please tell me to how to start specifically from eclipse-scala enviroment. Thankyou.

Comment: http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/gettingstarted.html - getting started with the Scala IDE for eclipse. Then add any of the above to your Maven build file (Java Image IO is part of the JDK).

Comment: Sorry no solution i already had that and i am stuck.